# Instagram account is missing the `Embeds` setting and can not connect/integrate with Juicer

Tags: instagram, integration, embed

I'm working on configuring a Juicer implementation ("Large" plan) and can not get a specific Instagram account connected. It works easily, first try, with other Instagram accounts, but the only difference that I can see with the one that doesn't work is that it does not have the "Embeds" setting under Settings > How others interact with you, which is between "Story" and "Comments." On the accounts that work, whether that is checked or not doesn't seem to matter, but the option isn't even there on the account that doesn't work. Accounts are all public, not private, all settings basically the same except that one. No issues connecting Linkedin or Facebook pages.

In Juicer I go Connected Accounts > [+] after Instagram User Names > Insta creds > then I get the error "Sorry, something went wrong: Please try closing and re-opening your browser window."

Questions are - why would one Insta account not have that Embeds setting when others do? Is there a way to get that in there? Is there a workaround to get Juicer to embed as is?

I've tried multiple browsers and mobile, cleared cache and cookies, followed all the steps on their [troubleshooting page](https://help.juicer.io/hc/en-us/articles/360039938652-Adding-or-refreshing-your-Instagram-connections-Troubleshooting), and reached out to Juicer for support, which has been slow in response time.

The expectation is to see the Instagram window that prompts you to confirm 3rd party access and whether or not you want media included in that access.

Thanks!